# How can I limit locate command to search current directory?

Tags: locate

Locate search is not limitable to current directory:

I am trying to learn so I decided to write this script

```
cd /usr/share/doc && ls -R | grep "\.html" | sudo tee htmldoclist.txt
```

Then I want to pipe the doc list into locate command similar to

```
locate $(head -n 1 htmldoclist.txt)
```

but I want to use `cat`.

I want to save the output of this to `hlinks.txt` and use `sed` to append `file://` to line starts with pipe to `sed` as follows:

```
| sed -e 's/^/file:///g'
```

I expect to create a bunch of terminal hyperlinks for my documentation files stored in `/usr/share/docs`

Comment: And what is the exact problem, what are you not able to resolve?

Comment: locate command is not searching within current directory thus it is very slow I tried the -P option too. and  dirname $(ls -R /usr/share/doc | grep "\.html")

Comment: If I could grep and get previous line that would help too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like `find` would be more appropriate for the task, it will give your the list of files and filter them and then you can use `sed`:

```
find /usr/share/doc -iname '*html' | sed  's|^|file://|'
```

But `find` does a lot more, it can also format the output for you:

```
find /usr/share/doc -iname '*html' -printf 'file://%p\n'
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Worked much better and creates clickable links Ctrl click.

Comment: @noob_sabidiot please accept the answer if it worked for you. That's how the system works.

Comment: find /usr/share/doc -iname '*html' -printf 'file://%p\n' | less

Comment: Now to make an alias docs="\`find /usr/share/doc -iname '*html' -printf 'file://%p\n'\`"